# is there any conditional annotation in JUnit to mark few test cases to be skipped?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

As far as I know to skip a test case the simplest thing to do is to remove the `@Test` annotation, but to do it over a large number of test cases is cumbersome. I was wondering if there is any annotation available in JUnit to turn off few test cases conditionally.

Comment: The appropriate way is to use the @Ignore annotation, but it's not conditional.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hard to know if it is the `@Ignore` annotation that you are looking for, or if you actually want to turn off certain JUnit tests conditionally. Turning off testcases conditionally is done using `Assume`.

You can read about assumptions in the [release notes](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/ReleaseNotes4.4.html)  for junit 4.5

There's also a rather good thread here on stack over flow:
[Conditionally ignoring tests in JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4)

Answer (score 8):

As other people put here @Ignore ignores a test.

If you want something conditional that look at the junit assumptions.

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html

This works by looking at a condition and only proceeding to run the test if that condition is satisfied.  If the condition is false the test is effectively "ignored".

If you put this in a helper class and have it called from a number of your tests you can effectively use it in the way you want.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if that what the OP has wanted, but it is exactly what *I* was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`@Ignore`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html) annotation which you can add to a single test or test class to deactivate it.

If you need something conditional, you will have to create a custom test runner that you can register using

```
@RunWith(YourCustomTestRunner.class)
```

You could use that to define a custom annotation which uses expression language or references a system property to check whether a test should be run. But such a beast doesn't exist out of the box.

Comment: Don't know if he edited his question, but `@Ignore` is not conditional.

Comment: @Alan if I get the OP right, his interpretation of conditional is "whether he adds the annotation or not" :-)

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, by conditional I meant something like @RunIf(boleanExpression). but it seems such a thing is not available.

Comment: There is @RunIf annotation for the conditional test run.

Answer (score 2):

If you use JUnit 4.x, just use `@Ignore`. See [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html)

Comment: Don't know if he edited his question, but `@Ignore` is not conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use assumeTrue(your_condition) to skip the test if the condition is false.
In the following example junit will skip the test if the file doesn't exist.

```
File file = new File("path/to/your/file");
assumeTrue(file.exists());
```