# Stop JUnit test in @Before method without failing

Tags: java, junit

These are my testcases

```
class Mother {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        if (!this.getClass().isAnnotatedWith("Version20")) { // pseudo code
            /*
             * stop this test without failing!
             */
        }

        // further setup
    }
}


@Version20
class Child extends Mother {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // run only when Version == 20
    }
}
```

Is it possible to stop the test in Child in the @Before method of Mother without failing or assertTrue(false)?

edit:
I have more Versions @Version19, @Version18 etc.
my software is reading a configfile and outputting the result some tests are only applicable for special Versions.
I don't want to make the version check within the test method because i have a lot of small tests and don't like code duplication

Comment: Why not just use `@ignore`, if you're going to annotate the tests anyway?

Comment: How about adding the check for Version20 within the test method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditionally ignoring tests in JUnit 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4) previously - the result was that you can use the `Assume` class' methods to disable a test based on a *run-time* check (whereas `@Ignore` is a static condition).

That said, if you're **always** disabling them based on a specific annotation, it would seem that you don't actually need to do this at run-time.  Simply annotating the classes with `@Ignore` as well as `@Version20` would do the job, and would be arguably clearer.

Though I suspect you might be ignoring only if the test is running in "1.0 mode" - in which case it is a runtime introspection, and you could do this with something like:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
   if (!this.getClass().isAnnotatedWith("Version20")) {
      final String version = System.getProperty("my.app.test.version");
      org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(version.equals("2.0"));
   }
}
```