# Run specific test case in parametarized junit test case

Tags: java, junit

I created a parametrized JUnit test case. In this test case I defined the test cases in Object[][] each row represents one test case and all test cases will run at a time, now what I want is a way to run just one test case. 
let's say I want to run the 3rd test case so I want to tell junit to consider only the 2nd row of the object[][]? is there a way to do that?

Appreciate your response.
Thanks

Comment: Where's your self-contained example?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517300/junit-parameterized-tests-how-do-i-run-only-1-specific-test-from-intellij-eclip

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean but there are a few options:

1. Use Theories instead of Parameterized that way you can mark some tests as `@Test` and others as `@Theory`.
2. Use `assume` in the test to check the parameterized values apply to the test
3. Use the `Enclosed` test runner and isolate some tests in one inner class that does `Parameterized` and other tests in another inner class.

[Theories blog](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2010/02/07/junit-theories/)

[Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html)

[Enclosed](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can comment out the tests you don't want to run, like:

```
    @Parameters
    public static Collection stringVals() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            //{"SSS"},
            //{""},
            //{"abcd"},
            {"Hello world"}  //only run this
        });
    }
```

---

EDIT:
If you want to run different tests depending on the test cases, you can also ignore some test input with `Assume` class in JUnit 4+. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4)

Example:

Let's assume that you have two instance of class `Person`, and you want to test if they are dressed. In case of `sex.equals("male")`, you want to check if his `clothes` list contains `trousers`, but for `sex.equals("female")`, you want to check if she has `skirt` contained in her list of `clothes`.

So, you can build test like:

```
@Parameter(0)
public Person instance;


@Parameters
public static Collection clothes() {
    Person alice = new Person();
    alice.setSex("female");
    alice.addClothes("skirt");
    Person bob = new Person();
    bob.setSex("male");
    bob.addClothes("trousers");
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        {alice, "skirt"},
        {bob, "trousers"},
    });
}

@Test
public void testMaleDressed() {
    //Assume: ignore some test input. 
    //Note: Message is error output; when condition is satisfied, the following lines will run, if not: test ignored
    Assume.assumeTrue("Tested person: " + person + "is female, ignore!", instance.getSex().equals("male"));
    assertTrue(person.getClothes().contains("trousers"));
}

@Test
public void testFemaleDressed() {
    //Assume: ignore some test input. 
    //Note: Message is error output; when condition is satisfied, the following lines will run, if not: test ignored
    Assume.assumeTrue("Tested person: " + person + "is male, ignore!", instance.getSex().equals("female"));
    assertTrue(person.getClothes().contains("skirt"));
}
```

When you run all the tests, you will see

```
[0]
    - testMaleDressed(ignored)
    - testFemaleDressed(passed)

[1]
    - testMaleDressed(passed)
    - testFemaleDressed(ignored)
```

with no errors.