# JUnit parameterized tests: how do I run only 1 specific test from IntelliJ/Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, intellij-idea

I have a `@Parameterized` junit test that spawns 50 tests:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class NurseRosteringSolveAllTurtleTest ... {

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> getSolutionFilesAsParameters() {
        return ... // returns 50 Files.
    }

    public NurseRosteringSolveAllTurtleTest(File unsolvedDataFile) {
        ...
    }

    ...

    @Test
    public void solveDataFile() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Running it takes an hour (and it's impossible to shorten that time, they are integration tests). Test 28 fails.

How do I run test 28 alone, without running the other 49 tests? Without changing the actual code, by simply configuring a `-D` or something similar in IntelliJ's (or Eclipse's) run configuration.

Comment: I filed [an issue at junit's issue tracker](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/677)

Comment: I see your issue has had a response: "*There is no baked-in way to do this, so taking this as a feature request.*"  :-(

Comment: Any solutions for IntelliJ as of 2021?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse is now (as of the Mars M4 release) able to run not just a single test from the Parameterized test class but any kind of subtree.

This can be:

- all methods for a single data set as returned by the @Parameterized-method
- all datasets for a single @Test-method

And as already mentioned, the test can also be specified by entering the tests name into the "method" text filed within the launch configuration. There will be a marker indicating that the method doesn't exist, but the test will run anyway.

See [this blog post](http://blog.moritz.eysholdt.de/2014/11/new-eclipse-junit-feature-run-subtrees.html) for details.

Comment: This feature is currently available in IntelliJ as well.

Answer (score 22):

I just tested this in Eclipse with a simple parameterized test that always fails on test #4. One is able to right-click on the failed test and select ***Run***. Only that test then executes.

[image: test output]

Result:

[image: just test 4]

Frustratingly, I can't see what Eclipse did to solve the problem. Nothing is apparently altered in the run configuration. In particular, if you select to run the configuration a second time, it executes all the tests.

Some further testing shows that Eclipse will regenerate all 10 parameter values, but only uses the 4th value. (This was determined by embedding a print statement in the `@Parameters` method).

Comment: No idea why someone would downvote this answer, because this is a very interesting lead. The question is whether eclipse hacks it or if it's using an unknown environment variable of JUnit 4. In the latter case, we should be able to mimic it in the IntelliJ/Eclipse run configuration manually.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I think this might be a good question for the Eclipse mailing lists.

Comment: [Here's how eclipse implements it](http://blog.moritz.eysholdt.de/2014/11/new-eclipse-junit-feature-run-subtrees.html)

Comment: This feature is currently available in IntelliJ as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it will help, but you can try a trick which I used with Eclipse and JUnit parameterized tests.

In JUnit launch configuration in "Test method" field you can write the full name of parameterized test, in your example it should be something like this 'solveDataFile[28: /path/to/your/file]'. Eclipse will complain that method does not exist but will still lunch it successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the precise syntax.

Answer (score 2):

For a subset of tests ex( 27 & 28 ) Just add:

```
`.subList( startInclusive, stopExclusive );`
```

before returning your parameters collection.

Non consecutive subsets:

```
Collection<Object[]> c = Arrays.asList( data ).subList( startInclusive, stopExclusive );
c.add( another subset );
return c;
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to Miguel's answer, if you are using the JUnit 5's

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(resources = arrayOf("/sender.csv"))
```

you can go to your csv file and "comment out" some lines by prepending the `#` character to them.