# How do I run a single variant of a parametrized JUnit5 test from the code pane?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5

IntelliJ/GoLand has a [feature to run a single test from a table test](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/guide/tips/run-test-in-table-test/) through a gutter icon:

[image: IntelliJ Go tests screenshot]

In Java, I am using JUnit5. Can I write a parameterized test (which is JUnit equivalent of a table test) so that IntelliJ allows me to directly run it from the code pane with a specified combination of parameters?

Currently, the best I can do is to trigger running all versions of the parameterized test (one by one) and then select and rerun the variant I need from the results window. This is discussed in Q: [JUnit parameterized tests: how do I run only 1 specific test from IntelliJ/Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517300/junit-parameterized-tests-how-do-i-run-only-1-specific-test-from-intellij-eclip).

Comment: Currently it's not possible for JUnit in IDEA. And if gradle is used, then it's even less possible:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19897; 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-325859

Answer (score 1):

A simple and straightforward solution is to create another test method that calls the parameterized method with the parameters of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented two improvements to make working with parameterized tests easier for me.

First, when using file-backed `@MethodSource` parameterized test, I am sorting the test cases by file modification time. This way, what I've touched most recently gets tested first.

```
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "pipelineTest_{0}")
    @MethodSource("loadAllPipelines")
    void pipelineTest(String scriptName, String scriptPath) {
       // ...
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> loadAllPipelines() {
        Map<String, String> pipelines = TestUtils.getPipelineFiles()
        return pipelines.entrySet().sort(false, { Files.getLastModifiedTime(Path.of(it.getValue())) }).reverse().stream()
                .map({ entry -> Arguments.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) })
    }
```

Second, I've switched to running tests with IntelliJ runner and not through Gradle

[image: Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle]

This way, I can run the whole test method first, and then run individual parameterized test cases from the GUI

[image]

It's not the experience I asked for originally, but it is livable.