# How to prevent test running outside the a SuiteTest

Tags: junit4, spring-test

I've a group of test that must running only from a TestSuite and never directly because they need a resource that is instantiated at the suite setup level

So my test suite is

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({IT_LiquidBaseTest.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-config-test.xml"})
public class DBTestSuite {
    private static MysqldResource mysqldResource;
    ....
```

My Test are like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-config-test.xml"})
public class IT_LiquidBaseTest {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
```

So When I launch the suite all is fine but when I call maven it try to run the IT_LiquidBaseTest directly and fail.
I still need the dependency injection to get a datasource

Do you've an idea how to prevent maven surefire plugin making this but enable the run of the test suite

Thanks

Comment: i do it by checking stack (it should be different when calling standalone, from maven and from suite). but it's very dirty. but do you really need it? just check in test if the resource is prepared and if not then pass/fail the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `org.junit.Assume` to test for condition on your suite.

```
@Before
public void beforeMethod() {
     org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(DBTestSuite.someCondition());
     // rest of setup.
}
```

If asumption fails test is not run.

Please see top voted answer to question: [Conditionally ignoring tests in JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4)