# JUNIT Conditional Tests possible?

Tags: java, junit

I have a series of data each one containing info_A and info_B. I would like to:

```
if(info_A) {
  run Test A
} else if(!info_A) {
  run Test B
}
```

It is very important that only the Test actually run is shown in the JUnit GUI tree. How can I do this?

The following solutions do **not** work:

- If I use the `Assume.assumeTrue(conditon)`, I can `Ignore` a test but then it is *still displayed* as passed in the test.
- Doing this:
  `Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestStep1.class);`
  leads to the correct result but the JUnit tree is *not* built.
- Using @Catagories also shows the *failed* tests, which is also what I don't want.

Comment: It looks like this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1689261/376390) might also be a solution to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can [use `Assume`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) to turn tests on/off conditionally:

> A set of methods useful for stating assumptions about the conditions in which a test is meaningful. A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JUnit Rules.

There's a whole blog post dedicated to exactly your question [here](http://www.mikereedell.com/2011/12/15/JUnit-Conditional-Ignore-Using-Rules.html), but in short, you do the following:

1. Create a class that implements the `org.junit.rules.TestRule` interface. This interface contains the following method:
   `Statement apply(Statement base, Description description);`
   The `base` argument is actually your test, which you run by calling `base.execute()` -- well, the `apply()` method actually returns a `Statement` anonymous instance that will do that. In your anonymous `Statement` instance, you'll add the logic to determine whether or not the test should be run. See below for an example of a `TestRule` implementation that doesn't do anything except execute your test -- and yes, it's not particularly straighforward.
2. Once you've created your `TestRule` implementation, then you need to add the following lines to to your JUnit Test Class:
   `@Rule

    public MyTestRuleImpl conditionalTests;`
   Remember, the field *must* be public.

And that's it. Good luck -- as I said, you may have to hack a little, but I believe there's a fair amount explained in the blog post. Otherwise, there should be other information on the internets (or in the JUnit sourc code).

Here's a quick example of a TestRule implementation that doesn't do anything.

```
public abstract class SimpleRule implements TestRule {
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    base.evaluate();
                } catch (Throwable t) { 
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```