# Re-run failed test using Junit

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm trying to improve an existing system of automated Selenium test.
My goal is to repeat the tests that fails because of connections problem.
I've found and tried to follow this thread [How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately) that revealed itself quite useful.

In my case the suite is composed by classes, so I've tried to substitute @Rule with @ClassRule, in order to repeat for each try also the @Before and @After parts.
I'm sorry for my ignorance, but where am I supposed to place this rule? In my Suite class? Or in the Classes representing the test?

Answer (score 5):

I am the original answerer of [How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately)

If I understand correctly, the problem that you are having is due to the `@Before` being executed before the code in the `RetryRule`, and the `@After` being executed afterwards.

So your current behaviour is something like:

```
@Before
@Retry
test code
@Retry
@After
```

But you can implement your `@Before` and `@After` as a rule - there is a rule [ExternalResource](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.java) which does exactly that. You would implement `@Before` and `@After` as a rule:

```
@Rule public ExternalResource beforeAfter = new ExternalResource() {
    public void before() {
        // code that was in @Before
    }

    public void after() {
        // code that was in @After
    }
}
```

Then you don't need the `@Before` and `@After`. You can then chain these rules using [RuleChain](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.java). This forces an order of execution to your rules:

```
@Rule public RuleChain chain= RuleChain
                       .outerRule(new LoggingRule("outer rule")
                       .around(new LoggingRule("middle rule")
                       .around(new LoggingRule("inner rule");
```

so your final solution would be something like:

```
private ExternalResource beforeAfter = ...
private RetryRule retry = ...

@Rule public RuleChain chain = RuleChain
                               .outerRule(retry)
                               .around(beforeAfter);
```

Note that if you are using `RuleChain`, you no longer need the `@Rule` annotation on the `ExternalResource` and `RetryRule`, but you do on the `RuleChain`.

Comment: But in this solution, before and after will be called for every test, not one time for the all bunch of tests ? It could be problematic.

Comment: @Before/@After are run for each test - this is what the OP wants as far as I know

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution based on the one mentionned in the question.

It's a combinaison of a `@Rule`, **FailedRule** and a `@ClassRule`, **RetryRule**

```
public class RetryTest
{
    public static class FailedRule implements TestRule
    {       
        @Override
        public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description)
        {
             return new Statement()
             {
                    @Override
                    public void evaluate() throws Throwable
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            base.evaluate();
                        }
                        catch (Throwable t)
                        {
                            System.out.println(description.getDisplayName() + " failed");
                            retry.setNotGood();
                            if (retry.isLastTry())
                            {
                                System.out.println("No more retry !");
                                throw t;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Retrying.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            };
        }
    }

    public static class RetryRule implements TestRule
    {
        private int retryCount, currentTry;

        private boolean allGood = false;

        public RetryRule(int retryCount)
        {
            this.retryCount = retryCount;
            this.currentTry = 1;
        }

        public boolean isLastTry()
        {
            return currentTry == retryCount;
        }

        public void setNotGood()
        {
            allGood = false;
        }

        public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description)
        {
            return new Statement()
            {
                @Override
                public void evaluate() throws Throwable
                {
                    // implement retry logic here
                    for (; currentTry <= retryCount && !allGood; currentTry++)
                    {
                        allGood = true;
                        System.out.println("Try #" + currentTry);
                        base.evaluate();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @ClassRule
    public static RetryRule retry = new RetryRule(3);

    @Rule
    public FailedRule onFailed = new FailedRule();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before()
    {
        System.out.println("Before...");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void after()
    {
        System.out.println("...After\n");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        System.out.println("> test1 running");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("> test2 running");
        Object o = null;
        o.equals("foo");
    }
}
```

It gives :

```
Try #1
Before...
> test1 running
> test2 running
test2(RetryTest) failed
Retrying.
...After

Try #2
Before...
> test1 running
> test2 running
test2(RetryTest) failed
Retrying.
...After

Try #3
Before...
> test1 running
> test2 running
test2(RetryTest) failed
No more retry !
...After
```

If I am commenting the `o.equals("foo");` in `test2`, everything runs fine in the firt try :

```
Try #1
Before...
> test1 running
> test2 running
...After
```

Comment: That's a good start.  However, you can probably combine the 2 Rules and just have a RetryRule that keeps re-evaluating in a loop until the test passes or max retries.

Comment: But the op wants @ before and @ after to be executed before and after each retry, for the set of tests.

Answer (score 0):

You decorate the *test name* itself with the `@After` or `@Afterclass` attributes:

```
@After
@Test
@Category(SmokeTests.class)
public void testProductPageOnly() throws TimeoutException {
   //Some tests here.
}

@Afterclass
public static void SomeTest {
   //Some test here.
}
```

Something to note, `@Afterclass` will *always run*; even if you are using a `@Beforeclass` that throws an exception.

Comment: Won't this ALWAYS run the test twice, not just if it fails the first time?

Comment: @JohnB - As it is written, yes.  But this is of a benefit to the OP since his tests seem to fail due to connectivity issues, which can be transient in nature.

Comment: But if it passes the first time and fails the second time it will report a failure and he is twice as likely to get the failure.

Comment: Actually the point is to run the test twice only in the case of a failure on the first execution.

Comment: You can always use junit's [assume](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1689309/2796998) to conditionally run the test

Answer (score 0):

May this can solve problem:

1) Test class should be inherited from `junit.framework.TestCase`

2) Run your tests with something like this

```
YourTestClass testClass = new YourTestClass();
TestResult result = testClass.run();
Enumeration<TestFailure> failures = result.failures();
if (result.failureCount() != 0)
{
   TestFailure fail = failes.nextElement();
   junit.framework.Test test = fail.failedTest();
   test.run( result );
}
```

At the end `result` will contains last results of test running, so after analyzing what test was failed you can run it again.

Comment: Unless you're unable to upgrade to JUnit 4.x or need pre-Java 5 compatability, you shouldn't be extending/using any of the ```junit.framework.*``` classes