# How can I run a test class only if another test was passed?

Tags: java, testing, junit, test-suite

I am doing some Junit testing and I need to know how to run a Test class only if a specific test from another class was passed.

Comment: You shouldn't ideally depend on other testcase to run a testcase. Make them as one testcase.

Answer (score 0):

There is 'Categories' feature in JUnit. (See: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories)

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been replied in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689309/1587081)

In the @Before function you need to retreive a runtime value from your system and check that it matches your requirement. Everything will stop if it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, This is bad practice, even in a well-designed Integration test-suite. I would encourage you to rethink your overall test class design.

If these tests are truly meant to be ***unit tests***, they should be atomic and independent of each other. See [this post](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2005/07/20/qualities-of-a-good-unit-test/) for a good read.

Having said that, I have often used JUnit 4.x to build & run rather large suites of Integration tests (backend functional tests that test a RESTful services responses). If this is your use case, I recommend restructuring your tests such that you never have one test in TestClassA depend on a test in TestClassB. That is a bad idea, as it will making your tests more fragile. And difficult for other devs to understand the intention of your tests, taken together as a whole.

When I have found that I have dependencies across multiple test classes, I have factored out a "test-superclass" to both test classes and do my "setup work" in that superclass. Or you can factor out a utility class that contains static methods for creating somewhat complex test conditions to start with.

But, even using JUnit as a vehicle to run these kind of "integration" tests should be done with caution and careful intent.

Comment: This doesn't mean test B must run after test A, it may be that test A is fast and checks if the app starts and test B is slow and checks something more specific so why bother with test B if test A failed.

Comment: @CaptainMan: To clarify, I was specifically addressing the original poster's question: "I am doing some Junit testing and I need to know how to run a Test class only if a specific test from another class was passed."  That question is *exactly* "test [class] B must run after test A"

Comment: I think I poorly worded my point. What I am trying to say is that there is a difference (but I agree, a small one) between "How can I run B after A" and "How can I run B only if A passes".

Comment: @CaptainMan: I see. Agree with that.