# Gradle android, how to exclude a single unit test

Tags: android, gradle

I have an android project with unit and integration tests in the same folder. If I run `./gradlew test` all of them are run, but I just need to exclude the cucumber tests from running, at the moment I just need to actually exclude to run the class with the annotation `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cucumber is not standard install in gradle. Are you calling jar or using gradle-cucumber plugin? Both have options for filtering by tag. https://github.com/samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin

Comment: when you say unit and integration tests in same folder, do you mean local (run on your machine) and instrumented (run on a device) tests in the same folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of adding a test closure like below does not work for some reason with gradle android plugin:

```
test {
  exclude 'com/example/MyTest.*'

}
```

Instead I have found the following option. Use the @Ignore annotation on your test(s). You can also conditionally ignore the test (e.g. based on a system property like RUN_AUTOMATION_TEST=false) using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689309/256770)

If you are using spock rather than junit then use something like this:

```
@IgnoreIf( {System.getProperty('RUN_AUTOMATION_TESTS') == null} )
public class MainScreenSpec extends BaseUiAutomationSpec {
}
```

Comment: Is this still actual?