# How to skip a scenario with Cucumber-JVM at run-time in JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I need to skip a scenario from running based on a flag which I obtain from the application dynamically in run-time, which tells whether the feature to be tested is enabled. I don't want to throw any exception.

Sample code:

```
            if (JIRA_Integration.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                status = zapi.getTestExecutionStatusInJIRA(scenario.getName());
                if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("pass")){
                    isScenarioAlreadyExecuted = true;
                }else {
                    isScenarioAlreadyExecuted = false;
                }
            } else {
                logger.info("Currently JIRA_Integration is disabled, enable it to update test scenario execution status in JIRA");
            }
        }

        if(isScenarioAlreadyExecuted){
            logger.info("Scenario: \"" + scenario.getName() + "\" is already passed in the previous test cycle");
            throw new AssumptionViolatedException("Scenario: \"" + scenario.getName() + "\" is already passed in the previous test cycle");
        }
```

Comment: You might look into this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4

Comment: Same approach I am using in my code above. Problem with above approach is failed test still shows up as Error in the test summary. I want these scenario/test to be skipped completely or proceed with next scenario/test.

Comment: If you're taking the same approach, it's anything but clear that this is the case from your code fragment. I bet you have a similar idea, but your execution is completely different.

Comment: Consider not throwing the Exception?