# Ignore all test case in whole project

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Need to ignore all the test class in my project. I knew we can use `@Ignore`. But I need to know if there is any way to ignore them at a project level.

Comment: Uhm... don't run the tests?

Comment: lol @FedericoklezCulloca i need to do in java code..

Comment: Then please specify what you mean, because as it stands your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Instead of adding @Ignore in all the classes, is there any other way to make it ?

Comment: Let me rephrase my point: why? Why do this when you can simply *not* run the tests?

Comment: Are you running the tests in an IDE or Maven?  You can add a property to skip tests in Maven.  The IDE will require more work, but that's Federico's point: Just don't run the tests.

Comment: In my test environment, by default it will run all test class. i dont have access to change the configuration.if want to stop i need to add @Ignore in all my test class. So is there is any way to make it simple ??

Comment: Can you avoid sending the test classes to the environment? Or send a dummy one?

Comment: I can not avoid. i need to do through code!

Comment: It's a shame you're not using junit5, because it has [this](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/condition/EnabledIfEnvironmentVariable.html) which means you could put the annotation on all your classes and set the variable on all the environments where you want to run the tests but not on the test environment.

Comment: But it may be worthwhile to take some ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4) in your case. Hope it helps, somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Achieved..

In ***pom.xml*** file inside the `<properties>` i added below

```
<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
```

it will skip all the test cases in build level.

Comment: It would have helped if you answered when duffymo asked whether you were using maven :P