# How to skip test if a condition is failed Junit (Instrumentation) Testing Android

Tags: android, junit4, test-runner, android-junit, androidjunitrunner

I am writing test cases for a device testing in which I will have to check some Wifi, Messaging, Camera and Audio Apis but only if the device is capable of that Feature

Example :

```
@Test
public void testMessagingApi() throws Exception {
    ....some test method....
}
```

But this Test method should execute only if my device is capable of Messaging feature

```
public boolean isCapable(String feature) {
     Check some property to test if the feature is supported
     return supported;
}
```

The test should execute only if isCapable returns true else it should be ignored or skipped

How to write such a test class

Please someone help

Comment: Have a look over here, @RunIf should meet what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4

Comment: tried this with RuniF

    Test
    @RunIf(DatabaseIsConnected.class)
    public void addition_isCorrect() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }

 class DatabaseIsConnected implements Checker {
        Override
        public boolean satisfy() {
            return false;
        }
    }

Here I am purposely returning false but still test run and it shows pass 

Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

And if you change 2 + 2 to 1 + 1, does it fail? (Cound not comment above, not enough reputation ;)