# How to get @Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true) behaviour in junit4/testcontainers

Tags: docker, junit4, junit5, testcontainers

My codebase is ancient and is locked into JUnit4. I would like to integrate testcontainers with the project to incorporate docker containers in the automated tests.

My dev box (which I control) runs docker, however, my CI system (which I do not control) does not.

If I could use JUnit5, I would just add the `@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)` annotation, and the docker based test would run happily on my dev box, while being disabled on the CI machine.

What is the JUnit4 equivalent to `@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is something out-of-the-box for this in Testcontainers for JUnit 4. You can mirror the JUnit 5 feature with some custom code.

First, you need a way to conditionally execute tests. There is already a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4) for this available. Basically you use JUnit 4 Assumptions for this:

```
 @Before
 public void beforeMethod() {
     org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(someCondition());
     // rest of setup.
 }
```

You will need this for all your Docker related tests.

Next, `someCondition()` should evaluate whether Docker is available or not. The current Testcontainers (1.14.3) release uses the following code part for `@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)`:

```
private ConditionEvaluationResult evaluate(Testcontainers testcontainers) {
    if (testcontainers.disabledWithoutDocker()) {
        if (isDockerAvailable()) {
            return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("Docker is available");
        }
        return ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled("disabledWithoutDocker is true and Docker is not available");
    }
    return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("disabledWithoutDocker is false");
}

boolean isDockerAvailable() {
    try {
        DockerClientFactory.instance().client();
        return true;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So you could extract `isDockerAvailable()` to e.g. an abstract class that also includes the `@Before` and handle this for yourself:

```
public abstract class DockerizedTest {

  @Before
  public void shouldRunTest() {
    org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(isDockerAvailable());
  }

  boolean isDockerAvailable() {
    try {
      DockerClientFactory.instance().client();
      return true;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

and now all your Docker related tests can extend `DockerizedTest`. Whenever the assumption evaluates to false, the test will be ignored.

If `@Before` is too *late*, you can use the same approach with `@BeforeClass`.

Comment: I've tried this solution on 1.15.3 even there is a method now 'DockerClientFactory.instance().isDockerAvailable()',  but it just takes a lot of time trying diferent 'strategies' and then it fails.

May be it has to do in my case that docker is installed as a service, and I just stopped it (Linux Desktop).