# How to execute test classes conditionally using Junit 4.11

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have multiple test classes and I want to execute test classes based on a bean value.

My test class:

```
@autowired
protected String abType;

public  class abTest extends TestAbstract {

@Test
public void testAddUser() {
---------
--------
--------
}
```

I want this class or its test cases to execute only when abType = a;

TestAbstract class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context-test.xml")
public abstract class TestAbstract {

 @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

This class is extended by all the test classes, I want to run all the test classes conditionally based on the beanValue which is configured in config.properties file.

I read multiple posts related to this, but didn't got what I am actually looking for.
Any help would be really appreciated.!!

Comment: Is junit5 an option? I would be a lot easier.

Comment: We are using spring 3, is junit5 compatible with it.?

Comment: also we are using java7, i guess junit5 won't work then.?

Comment: No. (you mean Spring3 from 2009? sorry) it's not "built-in" compatible with Spring3, and not with java 7 So another option is to use either Rules or assumethat. But you should at least upgrade to java 8 !

Comment: Right, we are working on upgrading to java8. But as the code base is huge. So, it will take some time. But yes, we will surely do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the assumeTrue in JUnit4. Maybe this is an option for you.

```
@Test
public void testOnlyWhenConditionTrue() {
   assumeTrue(conditionTrue);
   ... // your test steps
}
```

[Assumptions and Conditional Test Execution with JUnit 4 and 5](https://reflectoring.io/conditional-junit4-junit5-tests/)

Comment: I tried this with @before and my condition is returning false for the testclasses I don't want to execute. So, i am getting an error  org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: got: <false>, expected: is <true> in console. Is this the correct way.?

Comment: Yes, this should be correct. It executes everything before it comes to the assumption. But in the execution stats of JUnit it should show ignored instead of failed.

Comment: Yes, it is showing ignored. I was only concerned about the AssumptionViolatedException thrown at console. If it could be handled in a better way

Comment: There is an older Stackover question similar to your question. Have you checked it out [Conditionally ignoring tests in JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4?noredirect=1&lq=1)