# A proper way to conditionally ignore tests in JUnit5?

Tags: testing, junit, junit5

I've been spotting a lot of these in my project's tests:

```
    @Test
    void someTest() throws IOException {
        if (checkIfTestIsDisabled(SOME_FLAG)) return;
        //... the test starts now
```

Is there an alternative to adding a line at the beginning of each test? For example in JUnit4 there is an [old project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689261/4828060) that provides an annotation `@RunIf(somecondition)` and I was wondering if there is something similar in JUnit5?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4):

Tests can be disabled with `@DisabledIf` and a custom condition.

```java
@Test
@DisabledIf("customCondition")
void disabled() {
    // ...
}

boolean customCondition() {
    return true;
}
```

See also the user guide about [custom conditions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution-custom).

Comment: I wonder why I wasn't able to find that solution when I was researching about it. Thank you